HTML5 input field with form attribute ignores typed input
I have a form with two input type=text fields outside the form tags.   I'm using the HTML5 form attribute on the input fields. In my PHP $_POST I get the original values, regardless of what I type in the input (09:00 and 13:00 in the example below).
I tried in both Chrome and Firefox, with the same result.
What am I doing wrong?
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        28 Aug 2024 <input type="text" name="etd" value="09:00" form='41139'>
      </td>
      <td>
        28 Aug 2024 <input type="text" name="eta" value="13:00" form='41139'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="itinerary.php" method="post" id="41139">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


UPDATE:
As suggested, I looked at it in Chrome Developer Tools.  Both sets of values are being submitted. The defaults from value= and the ones typed in:


etd: 11:00,
eta: 16:00,
itinerary_id: 41139,
submit: Save,
etd: 09:00,
eta: 13:00


UPDATE to add one piece of relevant information. I had two versions of the form, one for mobile-width screens and one for desktop-width screens, with visibility controlled by a CSS media query. Although only one or the other was visible, both were in the HTML. I mistakenly gave both the same ID, and both sets of etd and eta input fields referred to that same ID. I'm now giving myself a facepalm.


@MisterJojo not necessarily however it could be an issue of a numeric ID

I'm not able to replicate the described behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/b9unq8mj/  When I observe the resulting POST request in my browser's debugging tools, the expected values are sent.  Can you update this to a runnable code snippet which demonstrates otherwise?

Also NEVER call anything in a form name or id=submit if you want to submit the form using script

I have a form with two input type=text fields outside the form tags Why, exactly, are they outside the <form> tag?

Because the actual page has multiple rows, one form on each row.  In order to line things up in columns, those two inputs are in their own table cells. It wouldn't be proper HTML to put the form around the table row.

David, thanks for your jsfiddle.  I saw that yours correctly only submits one set of values. That lead me to realize what I did wrong (see my answer below). You're right, I should have done that myself!

OK, I realized my mistake. I have two versions of the form, one for narrow (mobile) screens and one for wide screens. Both include the two inputs fields outside of the form.  I used the same id for both! The browser did exactly what I told it to do.
